# Recovering a password for a class mySQL server

Tags: mysql, passwords, password-recovery

So for a lab I need to access our `mySQL server` we're working on in a `DBMS` class. Whenever I enter `'mysqlsh -u root -p'` on my terminal(using a Mac) I get the error:

> ERROR: MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I showed this to my professor and they told me that it was because I kept entering the wrong password. Ultimately I can't seem to remember what password I used to get into the local host so I was wondering if someone could help me recover/reset my password. My professor had us download the mysql server and the mysql shell as well as the mysql workbench, adding as much info as I can to help others help me.